# Covering of a compact set, where the sets are not necessarily open.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K = [-1,1]$; for example, and lets say there exists a cover of $K$, namely:
$$K \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}S_i.$$
I did not specify if each $S_i$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$ is open, does there exist a finite sub cover of $K$ such that
$$K \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{k}S_i', $$

where $S_{i}' = S_{j}, i \in 1..k,j\in \mathbb{N}?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not at all. Take any injective sequence $(x_n)$ in $K$. Define
$$S_{n+1} = \{x_n\}$$
for $n \ge 1$ and
$$S_1 = K \setminus \bigcup_{n=2}^\infty S_n.$$
Then the $S_n$ sets partitition $K$, hence they cover $K$, but no proper subcover will cover $K$.